# IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Until yesterday, everything worked fine, but today I have such a problem when submitting the form (submitted successfully) with this error.
After refreshing the page, everything is stabilized.
This problem are just in my laptop , in other pc are good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem, i don't know what exactly was. But I noticed that my app was doing Http Get calls with multipart/form-data.

I opened Chrome and I updated to latest version, then I restarted Chrome and all worked. Despite this, I think just restart Chrome solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's what happened. the problem was in the browser. Thank you